# Full Disk Encryption and GPT partitions (TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt)

Tags: truecrypt, veracrypt

I'm aware that full disk encryption does not work with GPT partitions, but I was wondering WHY they don't and I can't find the info through Google.

What is the problem that is preventing it? From the VeraCrypt forums I saw the project coordinator mention "As of today, no open source implementation of UEFI boot encryption for Windows exists and we hope to be the first to release such implementation." But this was timestamped mid last year. I know Linux had some problems with secure boot previously but that got solved, so why does this issue persist? What is the difference in reasoning for Linux being able to boot (and do full disk through something like dm-crypt) and VeraCrypt not?

Comment: WDE obviously works with GPT partitions, otherwise we wouldn't have Bitlocker. So, it's a limitation of specific applications (more specifically, probably just a limitation of time/resources/skill for the developers of those - mostly open-source and volunteer-made - applications) rather than a flat-out impossibility.

Comment: So is that statement true about what the developer said? Or was it true then and not now? Still, I'm wondering what the complications are. They said it was top priority a year ago. So how "hard" is it to do? What are the complications? Why can they encrypt msdos partitions but not gpt? I want to understand what the complications are, I figured it was impossible but how "hard" is it?

Comment: The developer's statement is probably accurate - I'm not aware of any non-commercial or open-source solutions for WDE on GPT volumes. But the existence of commercial solutions demonstrates it's not an impossible task. I'm not familiar enough with the intricacies of the file systems or the operations of the drive encryption software to say why it is so hard. But it stands to reason that a change like this would certainly be non-trivial regardless of who the developers are. It's just harder for folks who aren't being commercially funded to prioritize it.

Comment: Yeah, I understand the pitfalls of OpenSource. I whole heatedly appreciate what these guys are doing. I just want to understand the reasons why it is taking so long. And the security/programming side of it is interesting to me.

Comment: @Iszi I did also want to draw attention to the mention of dm-crypt in my post. Can't this do GPT? And this is Linux and open source.